# What is the technical name for the short exaggerated anime scenes?

Tags: anime-production, tropes

You know, those scenes that typically cut to out of context OTT animations to exaggerate reactions? e.g. when a character is angry the whole screen might be taken over by swirling colours, angry eyes and shouty mouth. There must be a technical name for these scenes amongst animators and storyboarders. What is the term for it?

Answer (score 2):

The term this goes by is `Exaggerated emotional iconography` or even [Manga iconography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_iconography), which is one of anime's trademark tropes. This is due to anime often being an adaption from manga, where it is harder to convey emotion without the use of screen tones, backgrounds, or some form of over exaggeration.

These effects often find their way into Animes, and is more often referred to under a more catch-all term: [Manga effects](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MangaEffects).

Manga effects is a pretty broad term in this sense, which is in part due to all artists having their own way to convey emotions in their source work. Hence the effects falling under this category can range anywhere from 
 [Bishie sparkle](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BishieSparkle) to [face faults](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FaceFault) and so on.